# How to configure delay time in Spring-retry (Spring Boot)

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot

Is it possible to configure the `@Retryable` ? This methods **(getCurrentRate)** will be invoked 3 times. At first is 5 min, after that 10 min, lastly 15 min. How can I configure that ?

```
@Retryable(maxAttempts=3,value=RuntimeException.class,backoff = @Backoff(delay = 1000))
```

**Example**

```
public class RealExchangeRateCalculator implements ExchangeRateCalculator {

    private static final double BASE_EXCHANGE_RATE = 1.09;
    private int attempts = 0;
    private SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");

   @Retryable(maxAttempts=3,value=RuntimeException.class,backoff = @Backoff(delay = 1000))
    public Double getCurrentRate() {

        System.out.println("Calculating - Attempt " + attempts + " at " + sdf.format(new Date()));
        attempts++;

        try {
            HttpResponse<JsonNode> response = Unirest.get("http://rate-exchange.herokuapp.com/fetchRate")
                .queryString("from", "EUR")
                .queryString("to","USD")
                .asJson();

            switch (response.getStatus()) {
            case 200:
                return response.getBody().getObject().getDouble("Rate");
            case 503:
                throw new RuntimeException("Server Response: " + response.getStatus());
            default:
                throw new IllegalStateException("Server not ready");
            }
        } catch (UnirestException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    @Recover
    public Double recover(RuntimeException e){
        System.out.println("Recovering - returning safe value");
        return BASE_EXCHANGE_RATE;
    }

}
```

Comment: Delay is added by backoff annotation, backoff = @Backoff(delay = 300000, multiplier = 2), this value is in milliseconds,                            
                                                                                                              
With no explicit settings the default is a fixed delay of 1000ms
Only the delay() set: the backoff is a fixed delay with that value
When delay() and maxDelay() are set the backoff is uniformly distributed between the two values
With delay(), maxDelay() and multiplier() the backoff is exponentially growing up to the maximum value

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can achieve that with this configuration:

```
@Retryable(
  maxAttempts=3,
  value=RuntimeException.class,
  backoff = @Backoff(
    delay = 300000,
    multiplier = 2,
    maxDelay = 900000
  )
)
```

---

Invocations:

1. After 5m  ~ `Delay = 300000`
2. After 10m ~ `Delay = 300000 * 2 = 600000`
3. After 15m ~ `Delay = 600000 * 2 = 1200000 with Max Delay of 900000`

Comment: what is max delay ?

Comment: `maxDelay` is the maximum wait between retries, in milliseconds. In your case, it should be 90000ms ~ 15m.

With `delay`, `maxDelay` and `multiplier`, the backoff is exponentially growing up to the maximum value.

More info here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-retry/docs/api/current/org/springframework/retry/annotation/Backoff.html#maxDelay()

Comment: It stop running after second

Comment: Did you change the `Retryable` configuration? As I posted here, if it is throwing a `RuntimeException` it must wait for `5m`.

Comment: Do you even need to set maxDelay? You are already setting maxAttempts.

Comment: Indeed @wild_nothing. No need to set the `maxDelay` in this case.

Comment: This isn't correct. Please note that `maxAttemps` already [includes the first failure](https://docs.spring.io/spring-retry/docs/api/current/org/springframework/retry/annotation/Retryable.html#maxAttempts--), therefor **max 2 retries** will be made.
If you need 3 retries, then set `maxAttempts=4`.
Also, setting `maxDelay` is necessary to limit the time between the executions. Otherwise the third retry (fourth invocation) would kick in after 20 mins instead of 15.